# How can I obtain the name of an element using LET and WHERE?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I have a `xml` with some elements:

```
<tienda>
  <formacion>
    <curso id="1">
      <nombre>Android</nombre>
      <plazas>20</plazas>
    </curso>
    <curso id="2">
      <nombre>iOS</nombre>
      <plazas>15</plazas>
    </curso>
    <curso id="3">
      <nombre>SEM / SEO</nombre>
      <plazas>55</plazas>
    </curso>
    <curso id="4">
      <nombre>Photoshop</nombre>
      <plazas>10</plazas>
    </curso>
    <curso id="5">
      <nombre>RPAS</nombre>
      <plazas>5</plazas>
    </curso>
  </formacion>
</tienda>
```

I need to return the course (curso) that it has the minimum places (plazas) and in this example the course with less places is **RPAS**, because it has 5 `<plazas>5</plazas>`.

I have develop this xquery sentences:

```
for $f in doc("LMSGI06.1.xml")//formacion
let $minplazas := min($f/curso/plazas)
where $f/curso/plazas = $minplazas
return $f/curso/nombre
```

But this code does not retrieve me `<plazas>5</plazas>`, it return me:

```
<nombre>Android</nombre>
<nombre>iOS</nombre>
<nombre>SEM / SEO</nombre>
<nombre>Photoshop</nombre>
<nombre>RPAS</nombre>
```

Where is my error and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your loop on `$f` is bound to `<formacion>` elements, that is where the `where` clause applies. Then when you return `$f/curso/nombre`, it returns all `<nombre>` elements. You need to apply the contraint to the `<curso>` element.

There are many ways to do this, but without disturbing your outer loop, you can eliminate the `where` clause and apply the constraint by adding a predicate to the XPath in your `return` statement:

```
for $f in doc("LMSGI06.1.xml")//formacion
let $minplazas := min($f/curso/plazas)
return $f/curso[plazas = $minplazas]/nombre
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to sort the `curso` elements by the `plazas` (treated as an integer) and simply return the first item's `nombre`:

```
(for $curso in tienda/formacion/curso
order by $curso/xs:integer(plazas)
return $curso/nombre)[1]
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyiVhu/1

In XQuery 3 with higher-order function support you can even use the `sort` function with e.g.

```
sort(tienda/formacion/curso, (), function($c) { xs:integer($c/plazas) })[1]/nombre
```